# n-arm bandit with epsilon-greedy policy

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I want do understand epsilon-greedy policy. Consider a 3-armed bandit The reward functions are as follows:

```
arm1 : N(1, 0.5)
arm2 : N(0, 1)
arm3 : N(-2, 10)
```

I want to Train an agent with 1000 trials using -greedy policy with ∈{0.5,0.7,0.9} and plot the average reward regard each trial how can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

-greedy Policy only refers to the balancing between exploration and exploitation. And the epsilon should be the same for all the arms. Basically the multi-armed bandit problem refers to having several "arms" that you can pull, like in slot machines, and you need to figure out what is the best action to take at each point.

-greedy helps the algorithm selecting between choosing an arm at random and the best arm according to the current estimated value you have saved for each arm at the current state. For example, for  = 0.3, you will choose random actions 30% of the time and choose actions according to your policy 70% of the time.

The policy could be given for example by the best value between the averaged reward from each arm. Example pseudo-code:

```
values = [0]*n_arms
t_visted = [0] * n_arms
eps = 0.3
for episode in range(1000):
    rnd = random between 0 and 1
    if rnd < eps:
        arm = Random between all arms
    else:
        arm  = Select maximum between "values" array

    t_visited[arm] += 1
    values[arm] += 1/(t_visited[arm]) * (reward - values[arm]) # update value for that arm
```

The reward is calculated by the normal distribution you gave.

Comment: i wrote the code for this example pseudo-code how can i plot the average reward for given epsilons?